# COALESCE function returns no rows

Tags: sql, select, db2, coalesce

I have a problem with `COALESCE` function in DB2.

My statement:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ATTR,'NA') FROM TABLE WHERE %condition%
```

If ATTR is found based on condition then SELECT returns value of ATTR, but if ATTR is not found then I would expect SELECT returns "NA". However, it returns no rows.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What happens if you simply do "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE %condition%"?

Comment: `coalesce()` works on a single column value - it can't magically create a row from nowhere.

Comment: If I do "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE %condition%", then it returns one row with 3 columns, my point is WHEN there is no row then return VALUE 'NA'

Comment: If there is no row, then COALESCE() cannot be executed for any row (because none was SELECTed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To magically create a line:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'NA' AS ATTR FROM TABLE WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE %condition%)
UNION
SELECT ATTR FROM TABLE WHERE %condition%;
```

Explain: Select "NA" if the subquery returns no rows and union it with the subquery itself. Either one of the unioned sets is empty so it gives what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I know that it is a solution to this issue. However I can't use it. Because than the statement contains many table names and driver throws exception that statement contains too many table names.